# is that possible to write nested msg in one file?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, as the below example:

`Child.msg`:

```
float32 x
float32 y
```

`Parent.msg`:

```
Child[2] child
```

is that possible to use only one `.msg` file to implement?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410681/is-that-possible-to-write-nested-msg-in-one-file?/) by [fury.nerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/108548/fury.nerd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2022-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-12-20**:
I don't know the definitive answer if its possible, but I've never seen such a thing done and would be exceptionally unusual. Its best not. But you could consult the idl generators if its even feasibly possible, but I doubt that it is.

**Comment by [fury.nerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/108548/fury.nerd/) on 2022-12-20**:
well, thanks for the comment, it is indeed some kind of "idle curiosity", but somehow i just dont want to create too many `msg` files only use once, as exampled, if the `Child.msg` is only used by `Parent.msg`, it looks a little bit of wasting of managing/orginazing files...anyway, thanks for the comfirmation (negative comfirmation is also quit help for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No you cannot have more than one message per msg file. The filename is the name of the message and everything inside of the file is the contents of the message.

This sounds a bit like an XY problem. I would suggest that you consider asking a new question with more context if this is something beyond an idle curiosity about the design.

For reference the format is defined here: http://wiki.ros.org/msg

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fury.nerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/108548/fury.nerd/) on 2022-12-20**:
thanks for the explaination, as commented above, it is indeed some kind of "idle curiosity", and this confirmation though is not happy to know but quite clear, i dont need to do more investigations.